# Finding the time and space complexity of a monte carlo algorithm

Tags: algorithm, time-complexity, montecarlo, space-complexity, pi

I'm still new to StackOverflow so please forgive me if I did something wrong ^^'

I need help finding the time and space complexity of a Monte Carlo algorithm that approximates pi's value. I had a hard looking for answers on Google so I was hoping to find the answers here ^^.

Comment: *Which* Monte Carlo algorithm that approximates pi's value?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [this article](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/estimating-value-pi-using-monte-carlo/), it depends on `INTERVAL`. But you can change that depending on which precision you want. Basically, it `Defines precision for x and y values. More the interval, more the number of significant digits`

**Edit**

According to the article, the time complexity is O(N^2) where N is `INTERVAL`